# Get max consecutive occurrences of value in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this below:

Input:

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Output:

```
4
```

My algo:

```
streak = 0
max_streak = 0

arr.each do |n|
  if n == 1
    streak += 1
  else
    max_streak = streak if streak > max_streak
    streak = 0
  end
end

puts max_streak
```

Comment: If all elements can be expressed as characters, you can abuse regular expressions: `array.join.scan(/1+/).max.size` ;-)

Comment: Just a curiosity: why would you accept an answer which is basically a duplicate of an older one?

Comment: @DamienRoche is your array some kind of binary representation?

Comment: @Stefan no. It represents a string of losses/wins (0s, 1s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to [w0lf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29701123/477037), but skipping elements by returning `nil` from [`chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
array.chunk { |x| x == 1 || nil }.map { |_, x| x.size }.max
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't know that `nil` values are excluded from `chunk`ing

Comment: Awesome, didn't know you could do it this way either

Answer (score 6):

**Edit**: Another way to do this (that is less generic than Stefan's answer since you would have to flatten and split again if there was another number other than 0 and 1 in there, but easier to use in this case):

```
array.split(0).max.count
```

---

You can use:

```
array.chunk { |n| n }.select { |a| a.include?(1) }.map { |y, ys| ys.count}.max
```

ref: [Count sequential occurrences of element in ruby array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163605/count-sequential-occurrences-of-element-in-ruby-array)

Comment: very nice use of chunk!

Comment: In Ruby 2.2+ you can write `chunk(&:itself)` instead of `chunk { |y| y }`

Comment: This is equivalent to my deleted answer and it is incorrect, because it's not the same as OP's algorithm. This counts streaks of any number, not just streaks of `1`.

Comment: !!  This gets the maximum chunk - not specifically the max streak of `1` (if there is a bigger chunk of some other element in the array)

Comment: This appears to work: `array.chunk { |n| n }.select { |a| a.include?(1) }.map { |y, ys| ys.count}.max`. Feel free to update your answer or improve that.

Comment: @DamienRoche Updated - thanks, I misinterpreted question to think you wanted maximum consecutive occurrences of any number

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
p array.chunk{|x| x}.select{|x, xs| x == 1}.map{|x, xs| xs.size }.max
```

This *is* more concise, but if performance was important, I'd use your approach.

---

Edit: If you're in Ruby 2.2.2, you can also use the new `Enumerable#slice_when` method (assuming your input array consists of only `0`s and `1`s):

```
array.slice_when{|x,y| x < y }.map{|slice| slice.count 1 }.max
```

Comment: deleted my earlier comment above since Damien changed accepted answer but apologies for the misunderstanding. I've upvoted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

`array.split(0).group_by(&:size).max.first` `#=> 4`

The only bad thing - `split(0)`

Note: This only works with rails's ActiveSupport(extends Array with #split)

For ruby-only implementation

```
array.join.split("0").group_by(&:size).max.first #=> 4
```

Comment: I think it will fail with `NoMethodError: undefined method \`split' for [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]:Array`.

Comment: Did you mean to `join` first? Either way, doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, this method comes with rails's ActiveSupport